# How to remove/replace specials characters from a 'dynamic' regex/string on ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So I had this code working for a few months already, lets say I have a table called **Categories**, which has a string column called **name**, so I receive a `string` and I want to know if any category was mentioned (a mention occur when the string contains the substring: **@name_of_a_category**), the approach I follow for this was something like below:

```rb
categories.select { |category_i| content_received.downcase.match(/@#{category_i.downcase}/)}
```

That worked pretty well until today suddenly started to receive an exception `unmatched close parenthesis`, I realized that the categories names can contain special chars so I decided to not consider special chars or spaces anymore (don't want to add restrictions to the user and at the same time don't want to deal with those cases so the policy is just to ignore it).

So the question is there a clean way of removing these special chars (maintaining the **@**) and matching the string (don't want to modify the data just ignore it while looking for mentions)?

Comment: Do you have a list of the special characters you wish to remove or of the characters you wish to retain? It appears you wish to keep English letters, digits, whitespace and '@'. Is that correct?

Comment: Thx for the response @Cary Swoveland, i would like to ignore mainly the ones reserved for regex like for example the parenthesis which caused the exception in the first place

Comment: What do you mean, "mainly"? Can you be precise about what you want to keep or remove?

Comment: The first table here shows the reserved chars for regex in ruby(as I mentioned above I can ignore all special chars but in particular the reserved ones in order to avoid exceptions) https://bneijt.nl/pr/ruby-regular-expressions/

Comment: That is what I means; again thx for the response @CarySwoveland

Comment: And yes the character you mentioned are the one I would like to keep @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking around I found some answers on the platform but nothing with my specific requirements (maybe I missed something, if so please let me know), and this is how I fix it for my case:

```rb
content_received = 'pepe is watching a @comedy :)'

categories = ['comedy :)', 'terror']

temp_content = content_received.downcase

categories.select { |category_i| temp_content.gsub(/[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]/, '@' => '@').match?(/@#{category_i.downcase.
        gsub(/[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]/, '')}/) }
```

For the sake of the example, I reduced the categories to a simple array of strings, basically the first `gsub`, remove any character that is not a letter or a number (any special character) and replace each **@** with an **@**, the second `gsub` is a simpler version of the first one.

You can test the snippet above [here](https://repl.it/languages/ruby?v2=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```rb
prep_content_received = content_received.gsub(/[^\w\s]|_/,'')
p categories.select { |c| 
  prep_content_received.match?(/\b#{c.gsub(/[^\w\s]|_/, '').strip()}\b/i) 
}
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/ITE2zP)

*Details*:

- The `prep_content_received = content_received.gsub(/[^\w\s]|_/,'')` creates a copy of `content_received` with no special chars and `_`. Using it once reduced overhead if there are a lot of categories
- Then, you iterate over the `categories` list, and each time check if the `prep_content_received` matches `\b` (word boundary) + category with all special chars, `_` and leading/trailing whitespace stripped from it + `\b` in a case insensitive way (see the `/i` flag, no need to `.downcase`).